# Converting minutes/seconds string to milliseconds integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have song based objects with their duration attribute saved in milliseconds. In short I was looking for a way to take a string like this: `3:25` (3 minutes/25 seconds) and convert it to milliseconds. The problem I'm facing is that taking such a value and using it with `Time` wouldn't work to my knowledge since it would consider it a time of day vs minutes delimited by a semicolon. Was wondering the best way to parse and convert a value like this to be presented. Was also wondering of a way to convert back.

Comment: Perhaps `h, m = "3:25".split(":").map(&:to_i)` then `1000*(60*(60*h+m))`.

Comment: `h, remainder = 12300000.divmod(1000*60*60) #=> [3, 1500000]; h #=> 3; remainder #=> 1500000`. Then `"%d:%d" % [h, remainder/(1000*60)] #=> "3:25"` or `"#{h}:#{remainder/(1000*60)}" #=> "3:25"`. See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod).

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to post as an answer. I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Oh. One other note. `3:25` represents minutes and seconds. Not hours.

Comment: Then remove one `60` everywhere, of course.

Answer (score 0):

duration string to total milliseconds:

```
def custom_convertor(duration_str)  # format of duration_str -> "12:34"
  mins, secs = duration_str.split(":").map(&:to_i)
  1000*(60*mins+secs)
end
```